# PHP PDO - API Login

Tags: php, pdo

I'm doing an emulator for an API Login. I'm having a problem and I don't understand where it is from. Everytime I insert the credentials with the id and pass the url return me an error. ?LOGTOKEN=error

This is the basics

Settings.php

```
<?php

define('SQLITE3_CONN_STRING',   '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/htdocs/db/database.sq3');
define('API_TOKEN_NAME',        'LOGTOKEN');
define('API_SALT',              'salt');

?>
```

Api.php http://pastebin.com/QvEm3nA4

Functions.php

```
<?php
include_once 'settings.php';

function return_error($url, $tokenname = API_TOKEN_NAME)
{
    header("Location: $url?$tokenname=error");
}

function return_token($url, $token, $tokenname = API_TOKEN_NAME)
{
    header("Location: $url?$tokenname=$token");
}

function hash_password($pwd)
{
    return md5($pwd.constant('API_SALT'));
}

?>
```

Index.php http://pastebin.com/057T9GKZ

Comment: Please post all relevant code directly inside the question, shortened where it makes sense. Do not just post links to something, those will break with time...

Comment: @arkascha Yea I'm sorry but I posted lots of code to show you where I wrong cause I don't understand what Is incorrect.

Comment: Please copy those two chunks of code into the question. They might be a bit long, but it's better than using links that will break.

Comment: @halfer the most important two scripts are posted here without going to pastebin. I'm talking about Functions and Settings.php